# API used to know IP of the Interface in VC++?

Tags: visual-c++

I want to know the name of API which used to know current IP of the Interface.
I have two interface ethernet and WLAN.Both Interface are UP and i want to know IP of specific interface then Is there any API in VC++ that will give me interface IP ?

Thanks,
Neel

Answer (score 2):

[`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917(VS.85).aspx) or [`GetAdaptersAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Use [DnsQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
/************************************************************\  
    THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF  
    ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO  
    THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A  
    PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  

  Copyright © 2000  Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.  

/***************************************************************/   


/*  
   FILE:          Dnsquery.cpp  
   DESCRIPTION:   This sample illustrates the use of DnsQuery() function to send query to   
                  a DNS server to resolve the host name to an IP address and vice-versa.   

   PLATFORM:      Windows 2000  
   WRITTEN BY:    Rashmi Anoop   
   DATE:          3/22/2000  


*/   

/*    
  includes   
*/   


#include <windows.h>  //windows   
#include <windns.h>   //DNS api's   
#include <stdio.h>    //standard i/o   
#include <winsock.h>  //winsock   

#define BUFFER_LEN 255   


//Usage of the program   
void Usage(char *progname) {   
    fprintf(stderr,"Usage\n%s -n [OwnerName] -t [Type]  -s [DnsServerIp]\n",   
            progname);   
    fprintf(stderr,"Where:\n\t\"OwnerName\" is name of the owner of the record set being queried\n");   
    fprintf(stderr,"\t\"Type\" is the type of record set to be queried A or PTR\n");   
    fprintf(stderr,"\t\"DnsServerIp\"is the IP address of DNS server (in dotted decimal notation)");   
    fprintf(stderr,"to which the query should be sent\n");   
    exit(1);   
}   

//  the main function    
void __cdecl main(int argc, char *argv[])   

{   

    DNS_STATUS status;               // return value of  DnsQuery_A() function.   
    PDNS_RECORD pDnsRecord;          //pointer to DNS_RECORD structure   
    PIP4_ARRAY pSrvList = NULL;      //pinter to IP4_ARRAY structure   
    LPTSTR pOwnerName = NULL;        //owner name to be queried    
    WORD wType;                      //Type of the record to be queried   
    char DnsServIp[BUFFER_LEN];      //DNS server ip address   
    DNS_FREE_TYPE freetype ;   
    freetype =  DnsFreeRecordListDeep;   
    IN_ADDR ipaddr;   


    if (argc > 4) {   

        for (int i = 1; i < argc ; i++) {   

            if ( (argv[i][0] == '-') || (argv[i][0] == '/') ) {   

                switch (tolower(argv[i][1])) {   

                case 'n':   
                    pOwnerName = argv[++i];   
                    break;   

                case 't':   
                    if (!_stricmp(argv[i+1], "A") )   
                        wType = DNS_TYPE_A; //Query host records to resolve a name   
                    else if (!_stricmp(argv[i+1], "PTR") )   
                        wType = DNS_TYPE_PTR; //Query PTR records to resovle an IP address   
                    else   
                        Usage(argv[0]);   
                    i++;   
                    break;   

                case 's':   
                    // Allocate memory for IP4_ARRAY structure   
                    pSrvList = (PIP4_ARRAY) LocalAlloc(LPTR,sizeof(IP4_ARRAY));   
                    if (!pSrvList) {   
                        printf("Memory allocation failed \n");   
                        exit(1);   
                    }   
                    if (argv[++i]) {   
                        strncpy(DnsServIp, argv[i], sizeof(DnsServIp)-1 );   
                        DnsServIp[sizeof(DnsServIp)-1] = '\0';   
                        pSrvList->AddrCount = 1;   
                        pSrvList->AddrArray[0] = inet_addr(DnsServIp); //DNS server IP address   
                        if ( pSrvList->AddrArray[0] == INADDR_NONE ) {   
                            printf("Invalid DNS server IP address \n");   
                            Usage( argv[0] );   
                        }   
                        break;    
                    }   

                default:   
                    Usage(argv[0]);   
                    break;   
                }   
            }   
            else   
                Usage(argv[0]);        
        }      

    }   
    else   
        Usage(argv[0]);   


    // Calling function DnsQuery_A() to query Host or PTR records       

    status = DnsQuery_A(pOwnerName,                 //pointer to OwnerName    
                        wType,                      //Type of the record to be queried   
                        DNS_QUERY_BYPASS_CACHE,     // Bypasses the resolver cache on the lookup.    
                        pSrvList,                   //contains DNS server IP address   
                        &pDnsRecord,                //Resource record comprising the response   
                        NULL);                     //reserved for future use   

    if (status) {   
        if (wType == DNS_TYPE_A)   
            printf("Failed to query the host record for %s and the error is %d \n", pOwnerName, status);   
        else   
            printf("Failed to query the PTR record and the error is %d \n", status);   
    }   
    else {   
        if (wType == DNS_TYPE_A) {   

            //convert the Internet network address into a string   
            //in Internet standard dotted format.   
            ipaddr.S_un.S_addr = (pDnsRecord->Data.A.IpAddress);   
            printf("The IP address of the host %s is %s \n", pOwnerName,inet_ntoa(ipaddr));   

            // Free memory allocated for DNS records    


            DnsRecordListFree(pDnsRecord, freetype);   
        }   
        else {   
            printf("The host name is %s  \n",(pDnsRecord->Data.PTR.pNameHost));   

            // Free memory allocated for DNS records    


            DnsRecordListFree(pDnsRecord, freetype);   
        }   
    }   
    LocalFree(pSrvList);   

}
```

Output :

> DNSQuery.exe -n localhost  -t A
>   The IP address of the host localhost is 127.0.0.1

Comment: -1: The question asks for IP address of a network interface, not a domain name.